# Continuous allocation of 500kb from libBacktraceRecording.dylib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory, memory-management

I have a problem in iOS application that I am currently developing.

While running applications I am continuously having mysterious allocations of ~500kb.

I used instruments to track these allocations down, but the results are above of my knowledge.

So the instruments results looks like that:

[image: The results of Instruments Allocations tool]

As you can see there is continuos growth. Each "Generation" shows growth of approximately 500-600kb.

When I look into generation I see that the allocated memory goes to `VM: Performance tool data`:

[image: Insides of Generation B]

If I go deeper inside I see that the responsible library is `libBacktraceRecording.dylib`:

[image: Deeper insides of Generation B]

And then if I want to check the responsible for allocation place in my code sometimes I see calls which are related to `GCD`:

[image: Allocation in GCD]

And sometimes I get some kind of `Stack Trace` which doesn't directly relate to my code:

[image: Stack Trace]

What could be the reason of these allocations? 
It is not big amount, these 500-600 kb, but as it keeps growing after some time it kind of makes me worried. 
As I understand these allocations probably are not caused by me but by some kind of xCode performance monitoring tools or something like that. But is it true? 
And why it keeps growing without limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GMSPhoenixRenderer` is the Google Maps rendering engine.   More likely than not, it is gathering statistics related to performance or, as you say, it is the iOS dev tools doing so on its behalf.

You'll have to look in the GM* API to see if there is some way of disabling this.  I would suspect it is only turned on in DEBUG builds.

Comment: Actually yes, you were right. Yesterday I discovered that it is xcode's so called "Queue Debugging", which is included automatically in debug build. You can disable it in your project's scheme editor, just uncheck "Enable backtrace recording" under "Options tab". Thank you for suggestion.